# Deeplink in Ionic 2 is not working

Tags: ionic2, deep-linking

I am trying deeplinks with ionic 2 according to the procedure explained here, https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/ionic-deeplinks/

First I added the plugin using,
`ionic plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=http --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=cityknots.com`

Then in my `app.component.ts`

```
export class MyApp {
rootPage = Wrapper;

constructor(platform:Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
        // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
        StatusBar.styleDefault();

        Deeplinks.route({
            '/test': UserHome
        }).subscribe((match) => {
            console.log('Successfully routed', match);
        }, (nomatch) => {
            console.warn('Unmatched Route', nomatch);
        });

    });
}
```

}

I try to hit the url (http://cityknots.com/test in the ios simulator's browser (safari) after i've built and run the app, but nothing is happening. I expect the app should be launched and navigate to `UserHome` component. There is nothing in the console too related to this.

Comment: try ``https`` with URL_SCHEME=https

Comment: it's not working with https too

Comment: Hi @Anik , Have you actually solve this? Please do share how is this solved. Thanks.

Comment: I had to solve this using redirects, so from my server http://example.com/some-url, when the mobile app hits the url, i redirect to example://etc/etc this url, that's when the app triggers

Comment: I figured out that it's better to use the format `{'/test' : 'UserHome'}` with Ionic because of the lazy-loading page components.

Comment: i have not been working on ionic recently, I think lots of things have changed since then :)